Invalid assignment of property or key 'value' with value of type 'float' on a base object of type 'Nil'
I´m programming my own game in Godot 4.3 at the moment and i used a tutorial to make a healthbar, but im allways returning the error : Invalid assignment of property or key 'value' with value of type 'float' on a base object of type 'Nil'.
Here is my code from my Healthbar:
extends ProgressBar

@onready var timer = $Timer
@onready var damage_bar = $DamageBar
@onready var player = get_node("../../Player")


var health = 0 : set = _set_health


func _set_health(new_health):
    var prev_health = health
    health = min(max_value, new_health)
    value = health
    
    if health <= 0:
        queue_free()
    
    if health < prev_health:
        timer.start()
    else:
        damage_bar.value = health


func init_health(_health):
    health = _health
    max_value = health
    value = health
    damage_bar.max_value = health
    damage_bar.value = health

func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    damage_bar.value = health

My tree structure of the Healthbar:
My tree strucure if the Main szene
I did try to Fix it by browsing in the internet, asking friends and other stuff but none of the suggested thinks worked

Could you add the following: Which function throws the error? The error should show in which line the error occurs. Else you got add logs and look it up in the console. From the informations given it should be either init_health, set_health, or _on_timer_timeout.
if so damage_bar would be null in one of these functions. The reason for it is only speculation with the given code.
